# Вывести продаваемые компанией товары

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица **tovari** ,в ней есть столбец *id_company* , в этом столбце записаны ID компаний которые продают этот товар, записываю ID в этот столбец массивом вида 1,3,7 , после вывожу эти компании на страницу:

```
$directID = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE `id` = '".intval($_GET["id"])."' LIMIT 1"));

$company_bay_tov = explode(",", $directID['id_company']);

$catalog_company = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id IN (" . implode(", ", $company_bay_tov) . ") LIMIT 6"); 
while ($cc_bay = mysql_fetch_assoc($catalog_company)) { 
        //разметка
}
```

А теперь мне нужно вывести на странице компании товары которые она продает.
ID компании определяю переменной $directID['id']

Какой в моем случае должен быть запрос?

Comment: По моему 5 минут назад тут был такой же вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532311/mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/532322#532322   НО вообще ответ на ваш вопрос "никакой". нельзя в реляционных БД хранить id через запятую потому как сложно писать запросы, они не оптимизируемы. SQL на это не рассчитан. разворачивайте списки в связующие таблицы тогда вся работа с БД будет на порядок проще и с гораздо лучшим быстродействием.

Comment: А у Вас в первом запросе точно таблица company, а не tovari ? Не совсем понятно, зачем два запроса из company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый правильный вариант - пересмотреть структуру БД. Связь "многие-ко-многим" реализуется через дополнительную тамблицу: tov_com_rel(id_tovari, id_company). Ваш массив 1,3,7 превращается в три записи в этой таблице. По такой таблице элементарно находятся товары, которые продает компания. А также, компании, которые продают товар.

Но, если правильный вариант не подходит, то...

Не на чем проверить, пишу "вслепую", но примерно так:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tovary WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',','".$directID['id']."',','), CONCAT(',',id_company,',')) > 0");
```

то есть, к искому id добавляем по краям запятые и ищем подстроку в списке id_company, к которому тоже добавили запятые.

Comment: В MySQL нельзя складывать строки оператором `+`, только функцией concat. Да и find_in_set именно для таких случаев предназначен, о котором и написано в ответе на второй аналогичный вопрос, ссылка на который в комментариях выше. Я по дублю не начал этот закрывать потому как жду реакцию автора, вдруг все совсем не так :)

Comment: @Mike, значит не зря извинился за "слепой" ответ :) причем изначально написал с concat, а потом меня какая-то статься с толку сбила :(  Сейчас поправлю. find_in_set делает ровно тоже самое. Поиск подстроки менее привязан к диалекту SQL, и позволяет использовать любые разделители.

Comment: LOCATE можно еще на более популярный INSTR заменить и поменять аргументы местами. Но это все, конечно, к данной конкретной задаче мало относится.