# mysql поиск целого числа

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице есть строки с значениями:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне найти все строки где в столбце ids есть целое число "1", чтобы, в данном случае, на выходе получить строку c id 1.

Comment: А у вас там во второй строке между 35 и 14 стоит точка, это нормально  ? У вас дробный id или вместо запятой в данных может быть точка

Comment: Поменял картинку =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select *
  from table
 where find_in_set(1,ids)>0
```

НО настоятельно рекомендую изменить структуру базы и привести ее к [Нормальной форме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Т.е. создать еще одну таблицу в которой будут отдельные записи с id из первой таблицы и одним из значений из списка. Потому как поиск в списках через запятую для реляционных БД нетривиален и не поддается оптимизации (при любом запросе просматриваются все записи в БД)

Comment: Да я уже так и подумал.
Ибо у меня все равно есть вторая таблица, просто свяжу во второй по id из первой.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то:

```
select *
from table
where ids like '%,1,%'
   or ids like '%,1'
   or ids like '1,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from table
where a=1 or b=1 or c=1
```

Comment: Очевидно, что я изначально не правильно сформулировал вопрос - поправил.