# Поиск с участием сериализованного массива

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток. В ячейке базы хранится сериализованный массив вида ["10","36","11"], знаю, что лучше так не делать, но все же. Как реализовать проверку наличия хотя бы одного из значений этого массива во вложенной выборке. Например, если бы вместо массива было одно значение, то проверка выглядела бы так "value IN (SELECT)". Подскажите, пожалуйста, оптимальный вариант.

Comment: оптимальный вариант - привести базу к нормальной форме

Comment: Функция INSTR/LOCATE. Кавычки с запятыми делают необязательным контроль обрамления.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql поиск целого числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532311/mysql-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)