# Запрос WHERE захватывает лишние записи. Странное приведение типов

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, select, laravel-8

Наблюдаю странное поведение при выборке.

Данные выбираются из таблицы `'article'`, по колонке `'tag_id'` (статьи, у которых есть нужный тег)

ID тегов хранится как отдельное число или как числа, перечисленные через запятую `'1,5,10' или '10' или '19,14'`

Реализация в модели:

```
class Tags extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'tags';

    public function getArticleWithTags() {
        return Article::where('tag_id', $this->id)
                        ->orWhere('tag_id', 'like', $this->id.',%')
                        ->orWhere('tag_id', 'like', '%,'.$this->id)
                        ->orWhere('tag_id', 'like', '%,'.$this->id.',%')
                        ->get();
    }
}
```

Запятую нужно учитывать, для исключения однозначных вхождений в двухзначные, т.е. если использовать `where('tag_id', 'like', '%'.$this->id.'%')`, то при поиске `id=5`, в выборку так же попадут `id=15,25,51`, etc.

---

**Но что то пошло не так...**

При нормальном поведении в результаты запроса `'tags.id'='article.tag_id'`:

```
public function getArticleWithTags() {
    return Article::where('tag_id', '=', $this->id)->dd();
    //->get();
}
```

[image: dd()]

должны попадать данные **с точным соответствием** id из двух колонок.

Т.е. из запроса выше `select * from 'article' where 'tag_id' = 1` должны вернуться строки из таблицы, где в колонке `tag_id` стоит `1`

**Но** в выбокру так же попадают значения, у которых в колонке `tag_id` стоят следующие значения: `'1', '1,11', '1,9', '1,Z', '1,qwerty', '1qwerty'` при этом, как и положено, игнорируются: `'9,1', '19', 'abc,1'`.

---

Условие `where('tag_id', $this->id)` можно заменить на `where('tag_id', 'like', $this->id)`
Получив корректную работу:

```
return Article::where('tag_id', 'like', $this->id)
                    ->orWhere('tag_id', 'like', $this->id.',%')
                    ->orWhere('tag_id', 'like', '%,'.$this->id)
                    ->orWhere('tag_id', 'like', '%,'.$this->id.',%')
                    ->get();
}
```

Так же, конструкция `where('tag_id', $this->id)` будет корректно работать, если приводить передаваемый аргумент к строке:

```
return Article::where('tag_id', ''.$this->id)->get();
return Article::where('tag_id', (string)$this->id)->get();
return Article::where('tag_id', strval($this->id))->get();
```

[image: dd()]

Но вопросы остались...

Почему без приведения к строке попадают в выборку странные значения?

Типы колонок:

- tags.id - bigint(20)
- article.tag_id - varchar(255)

Получается сравнение идёт по первому символу

`select * from 'article' where [varchar(255)='1qwerty'] = [bigint(20)=1]`

Точнее из двух сравниваемых значений именно varchar приводится к числу, иначе (при приведении искомого id к строке) и результаты бы такие не появлялись и ручного приведения делать не пришлось бы, да и при явном приведении лишние данные из выборки пропадают

По итогу из varchar берётся первый символ, который видимо преобразуется в число. Или первый символ сравнивается после такой обрезки с id, преобразованным в строку, но тогда почему id не приводится к строке на более раннем этапе.

Для меня странно такое преобразование
В документации не видел комментариев по такому поведению.

Какие мысли? Что посмотреть по теме?
Буду признателен...

Comment: Добавлю, что если mysql видит числовое значение то он пытается все приводить к нему для сравнения. Так же добавлю, что хранить значения через запятую и сравнивать как текст крайне не рекомендуется. Возникают вот такие проблемы, да и полный скан таблицы гарантирован. И оперировать этим полем неудобно. Стоит рассмотреть нормализацию данных, вынесения перечислимых значений в отдельную таблицу, отдельными записями

Comment: Но если с нормализацией проблемы, то рекомендую использовать функцию find_in_set https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532322/194569

Comment: Благодарю за пояснения. Возможно позднее буду делать нормализацию, понимаю что некрасиво, но вопрос задал, т.к. интересовало именно поведение и преобразование. Не знал, что приводится к числу...
Спасибо за ответ.